# Where does the "busman's holiday" expression come from?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I understand the expression to mean doing something on a holiday that you would normally do at your job. So, am I to understand that the expression simply refers to a bus driver going for a ride on the bus on his day off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various dictionaries confirm this as the meaning and give the first use as 1893:  [Wordorigins.org](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/busmans_holiday/) points to it in *English Illustrated Magazine*.

> I shall indeed take a holiday soon,...but it will be a "Busman’s Holiday".

Comment: Just to expand the answer a little bit. Here's a [link to the article](http://books.google.com/books?id=jN4vAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA488&ots=zcx4nILGnZ&dq=english%20illustrated%20busman's%20holiday&pg=PA488#v=onepage&q=busman's%20holiday&f=false). It refers to a box-seat, so I believe that "busman" actually means a coach driver rather than the modern definition of a bus driver.